# Why use str(id)?

Tags: python

My SDK comes with code appearing with rows like this

```
id=str(profile["id"])
```

It makes me wonder why something like the following shouldn't work

```
id=profile["id"]
```

Casting I believe is expensive so either the same type can be used or polymorphism at the method called. Can you tell why I must cast the id to a string?
Thank you

Comment: This isn’t your question, but pylint complains about `Redefining built-in 'id'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no casting in Python. Str(67) does not cast. It calls the `__str__` method on the integer object, which generates a string representation of itself.

This is necessary to make sure that profile['id'] is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking that the assessment could be made implicit since there's no way the variable should be used as an integer.

Comment: Well, Python has strong typing, so if it has to be a string, it has to be a string.

Answer (score 3):

It turns profile[id] into a string, python doesn't do this automatically, and further along in the code, the program probably checks profile[id] against a string. Without this conversion, you would get a typeerror: Trying to compare a string with an integer.

Comment: You don't get a TypeError if you compare a string with a integer. But you don't get the desired result. Example: `1 == '1'` returns `False`

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. You get a TypeError when you try to concatenate a string and an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not do arbitrary run time type conversion. You can't use an integer as a string.

Comment: I understand. I guess I should look more closely how it's used to see why the "user" must do type-conversion which seems a bit unnecessary when the API could do it for us.

Answer (score 0):

It turns profile[id] into a string

Comment: The OP asks why to use `str` in this situation, not what `str` does.